# How do I fill multiple named fields using structured data

Tags: python, numpy, field, multiple-columns, structured-array

I would like to take the information from some fields and just write them into another variable using a list.

```
import numpy as np
var1 = np.array([(1,2,3,4),(11,22,33,44),(111,222,333,444)], dtype=([('field1', 'int32'),('field2','int32'),('field3','int32'),('field4','int32')]))
var2 = np.empty((1), dtype = ([('field1', 'int32'),('field2','int32'),('field5','int32'),('field6','int32')]))
myList = ['field1', 'field2']
```

I want to write the values from the 1st and 2nd fields and 1st row to var2. I try the following:

```
var2[(myList)] = var1[(myList)][0]
```

But I get the following error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

What I want to achieve the same if I perform:

```
var2['field1'] = var1['field1'][0]
var2['field2'] = var1['field2'][0]
```

How could I do this in order to able to perform this with higher lists avoiding a for loop over the list?

Answer (score 2):

A list of fields works for fetching a subset of the fields

```
In [139]: var1[myList]
Out[139]: 
array([(1, 2), (11, 22), (111, 222)], 
      dtype=[('field1', '<i4'), ('field2', '<i4')])
```

but not when used on the left side as a 'setter' (this may be an area of development).

```
In [138]: var2[myList]= var1[myList]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-570d16e71a2e> in <module>()
----> 1 var2[myList]= var1[myList]

IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

So you need to iterate on the fields.

```
for name in myList:
    var2[name] = var1[name][0]
```

Iterating on field names is common practice in structured array code (as in `np.rec` functions). Typically a structured array will have many elements ('rows') but a few fields ('columns'), so iteration over fields is not expensive.

---

In this case, all fields of `var2` are the same `int` dtype.  So I can perform the assignment on the corresponding 2d view

```
In [160]: var2.view(int)[:2] = var1[myList][0].tolist()
```

`var2` data buffer is all ints, so it can be viewed either as fields or a regular array (2d or 1).

`var2.view(int)[:2] = var1[myList][0]` assigns `var1['field1'][0]` to both items of `var2`.  So I have to make it into a list or tuple.

Alternatively I can view `var1` as well.  With this I found I need to `reshape` as well.  The `view` produces a 1d array view of the buffer.

```
var2.view(int)[:2]=var1.view(int).reshape((3,4))[0,:2]
```

Multifield assignment is under development, but I don't think it is in the official release yet.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6053

---

```
var1.view(int).reshape((3,4))  # or 
var1.view(int).reshape((-1,4))
```

can also be expressed as:

```
var1.view((int,4))
```

(the compound view is more compact, though not any faster).

Comment: I already tired this way, but I thought that it would be a more efficient way... Thank you anyway!

Comment: I could search the `numpy` `github` issues, and see if anyone is trying to add this to the structured array `__setitem__` method.

Comment: Since all the fields are ints, it possible to `view` these arrays as regular 1 or 2d ones, and use numeric indexing.