# Python numpy.where and structured (record) array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to use numpy.where with my array of records :

```
new_array = np.core.records.fromrecords([(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],ND‌​ate)],names='Date, Name, Age, Start, End,Avg,NDate',formats='S10,d,d,d,d,d,d')
```

I've tried this:

```
np.where(work.stock==6.26)
>>(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

Returned nothing, so I tried this:

```
np.where(work.stock==work.stock[6.26])
>>(array([6]),)
```

Returned number of the equal elements. But I just need the index of the first occurance. How can it be done?

Comment: Are you looking for `numpy.argwhere`?  I can't really tell ...

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure. I've just tried replace np.where by np.argwhere but it returns the same result. I need the index of the first occurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first statement I can construct a look alike array

```
new_array = np.core.records.fromrecords([(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)],
   names='Date, Name, Age, Start, End,Avg,NDate',
   formats='S10,d,d,d,d,d,d')
```

which displays as

```
rec.array([('1', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0)], 
    dtype=[('Date', 'S10'), ('Name', '<f8'), ('Age', '<f8'), 
    ('Start', '<f8'), ('End', '<f8'), ('Avg', '<f8'), ('NDate', '<f8')])
```

but your

np.where(work.stock==6.26)

leaves me scratching my head.  What is `work`?  Is `stock` a field of another array.  It's not a field of `new_array`.

np.where(work.stock==work.stock[6.26])

is equally puzzling.  How can you index an array with a float (6.26)?

Be careful about doing tests like `work.stock==6.26`.  Equality tests on floats often do not work, due to rounding errors.

Practice with `np.where` on simple arrays.  Start with integer ones before trying floats.  Learn what it produces when there aren't any matches, and when there are multiple ones.

If there is only one record in your `new_array` it might be better if you used simple Python lists.

---

Here's how you could use `where` to find the 1st record with a given value in a specified field

Define a small array with 2 fields, 4 records, and integer values (for ease of testing):

```
In [482]: X=np.core.records.fromrecords([(1,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,1),(1,2)],dtype='i,i')

In [483]: X
Out[483]: 
rec.array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 1), (1, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [484]: X['f0'] 
Out[484]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1])
```

The elements of `X['f0']` that are equal to `1` (integer)

```
In [486]: i=np.where(X['f0']==1)

In [487]: i
Out[487]: (array([0, 4]),)
```

And the index of the first one (the first [0] picks the array out of the tuple)

```
In [488]: i[0][0]
Out[488]: 0

In [489]: X[i[0][0]]
Out[489]: (1, 2)
```

Alternatively I could use the whole `i` to get all the `X` that meet this criteria

```
In [494]: X[i]
Out[494]: 
rec.array([(1, 2), (1, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

and select the first:

```
In [495]: X[i][0]
Out[495]: (1, 2)
```

If there aren't any matches, then `where` returns an empty array

```
In [496]: i=np.where(X['f0']==5)

In [497]: X[i]
Out[497]: 
rec.array([], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

A `where` test on a structured array field is really no different than a test on a row or column of a 2d array.

---

I changed `X.f0` to `X['f0']` because the record array notation can be confusing, and non-record structured arrays are more common these days, especially when arrays are generated by `np.getfromtxt`.

`X==2` returns `False`.  `X['f0']==2` returns `array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)`.  Boolean tests do not work across fields of a structured array.

To find 'rows' of `X` across all fields, I have to test against a matching structured array, e.g.

```
In [507]: X==np.array([(2,3)],dtype=X.dtype)
Out[507]: rec.array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`np.where` can work with that `Out[507]` boolean array.

---

Find `X` records where one field or the other has a `2`:

```
In [518]: I=(X['f0']==2) | (X['f1']==2)

In [519]: I
Out[519]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [520]: X[I]
Out[520]: 
rec.array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

I have to test each field individually.

In this case, all fields of `X` are integer, so I can construct a 2d integer view, and perform a test on that:

```
In [526]: np.any(X.view(int).reshape(X.shape[0],-1)==2,axis=1)
Out[526]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

See recent https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094425/901925 for more on using a `view` of a structured array.

Comment: Sorry I've missed to say that new_array  is  а part of a class "work" so  the correct call should be np.where(work.new_array==work.new_array[6.26]). Yes I've tried to practice with where function and it works fine for me even with float items but i used simple arrays just like yours. But cant figure out how to use it with structured array

Comment: For example I know that value 6.26 exists in Start column of new_array. So if i call it by np.where(work.stock['Start']==6.26) it gives me (array([27]),) - And its is correct 6.26 value is assigned to index 27. But I want to seach all array at once, mean all fields at once not filed by field

Comment: Just tried to search for integer value. I have one integer field but no luck the same result

Comment: I added an example of what can, and cannot be done, when searching across all the fields at once.